# Get time diff between windows and linux machine using java or any other API

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have a code running on Windows and Linux machine.
Message will be sent from windows to Linux machine and we include `sent_time` on message.
Linux machine will receive the message and we stamp `receive_time` on message.
Both the time are calculated using standard java API `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Problem here is, `receive_time` is ahead of `sent_time` which is not right as message was sent first and then received. This mostly looks to be clock sync issue between Windows and Linux machine.

How can we get the clock diff between Windows and Linux machine? (Not sure how to run program on both the machines and claculate time diff which is in millis)
if there is any sync issue, how can we get and add delta time `receive_time` ?

Please note that all the libraries are same on both machines.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find time deviations, maybe even synchronize clocks across the network. This adds complexity because neither of the two machines know how much lag is in the network passing the data.

The NTP protocol mitigates all this. I'd use an existing implementation. But if you do not want to synchronize the system clock but still understand how it is done, check out the protocol documentation: http://www.ntp.org/rfc.html